# Performance Issue in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any performance hit when we use any Expand (FillAndExpand, CenterAndExpand) attribute with any Layout (StackLayout or FlexLayout)? Any recommendation for how to use layout with considering the performance of the app.

Comment: You can check my blog here https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/techniques-for-improving-performance-in-a-xamarin-forms-application-b439f2f04156

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official documentation:

> Don't set the VerticalOptions and HorizontalOptions properties of a
>   layout unless required. The default values of LayoutOptions.Fill and
>   LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand allow for the best layout optimization.
>   Changing these properties has a cost and consumes memory, even when
>   setting them to the default values.

And,

> When using a StackLayout, ensure that only one child is set to
>   LayoutOptions.Expands. This property ensures that the specified child
>   will occupy the largest space that the StackLayout can give to it, and
>   it is wasteful to perform these calculations more than once.

So, having this in mind, try to simplify your layouts as possible, and only set Expand if it is really necessary.

You can read more information in [Xamarin Performance Doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance)